# Perl - multiple keys and merging two files

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodies;

#constants
use constant {
    FILE_A  => '/home/test/input_a.csv',
    FILE_B  => '/home/test/input_b.csv',
    FILE_C  => '/home/test/output.csv',
};

my %a_hash;

my @a_array;
my @b_array;
my @c_array;

open my $c_fh, "<", FILE_C;
open my $a_fh, "<", FILE_A;

while ( my $line = <$a_fh> ) {
    chomp $line;
    $line = /^(.+?);/; 
    $a_hash{$1} = 1; 
    print $c_fh, $line . "\n"; #populate a.csv into c.csv
}
close $a_fh;

open my $b_fh, "<", FILE_B;
#reading b.txt
while ( my $line = <$b_fh> ) {
    chomp $line;
    #your suggestion added
    $line = /^(.+?);/;
    if ( not exists $a_hash{$1} ) {
        print $c_fh, $line . "\n"; #populate a.csv into c.csv
    }
}
close $b_fh;
close $c_fh;
```

**Error message:**

```
Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at ./test.pl line 34, <$b_fh> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $1 in exists at ./test.pl line 35, <$b_fh> line 1.
```

Comment: why there is no `x002;juop88;jup;879` in `c.txt`?

Comment: Is that really the code that you're running?  Cut & pasted in its entirety?  I have never see `autodies`.

Answer (score 0):

Hashes are an excellent way to index files. You said:

> I need all the lines from a.txt into c.txt. But while selecting lines from b.txt into c.txt, first I need to look into a.txt. If the line is already present in a.txt, then I shouldn't consider that b.txt line while writing into c.txt [output].

This means you only really need to index the lines in `a.txt`. You also don't mention how you plan to merge file `a.txt` into `c.txt`. Do you read in one line from each file? Is the final output suppose to be sorted?

And, what do you mean by *matching line*? Do you mean the full line matches, or only up to the first semicolon matches?

To keep things flexible, I'm going to read in all the lines into various arrays and let you sort things out from there.

- We'll read in a.txt into an array and into a hash for indexing.
- We'll read in b.txt into another array, but we'll skip any lines that are in our hash index.
- We'll read in c.txt into yet another array.
- You can do what you want with these arrays and merge the lines anyway you like.

Here's the program:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

# Preliminary stuff. The first two are always a must
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodies;   # No need to test on read/write or open/close failures

# This is how Perl defines constants. It's not great
# And unlike variables, they don't easily interpolate in 
# strings. But, this is what is native to Perl. There are 
# optional modules like "Readonly" that do a better job.
use constant {
    FILE_A  => 'a.txt',
    FILE_B  => 'b.txt',
    FILE_C  => 'c.txt',
};

# I'll use this for indexing
my %a_hash;

# I'll put the file contents in these three arrays
my @a_array;
my @b_array;
my @c_array;

open my $a_fh, "<", FILE_A;

# I'm reading each line of FILE_A. As I read it,
# I'll get the first field and put that as an index
# to my hash

while ( my $line ~= <$a_fh> ) {
    chomp $line;
    $line = /^(.+?);/;     # This strips the first field from the line
    $a_hash{$1} = 1;       # Now, I'll use the first field as my index to my hash
    push @a_array, $line;  # This adds the line to the end of the array
}
close $a_fh;

# I'll do the same for FILE_B as I did for FILE_A
# I'll go through line by line and push them into @b_array.
# One slight difference. I'll pull out the first field in
# my line, and see if it exists in my %a_hash where I indexed
# the lines in FILE_A. If that line does not exist in my %a_hash
# index, I'll push it into my @b_array

open my $b_fh, "<", FILE_B;
while ( my $line = <$b_fh> ) {
    $line ~= /^(.+?);/;
    if ( not exists $a_hash{$1} ) {
        push @b_array, $line;
    }
}
close $b_fh;

# Now, I'll toss all the lines in FILE_C into @c_array
# I can do a bit of a shortcut because I don't process
# the lines. I'll just put the whole file into @c_array
# in one fell swoop. I can use "chomp" to remove the NL
# from the end of each item of @c_array in a single line.

open my $c_fh, "<", FILE_C;
@c_array = <$c_fh>;
chomp @c_array;
close $c_fh;

# At this point, @a_array contains the entire contents of FILE_A
# in the order of that file. @c_array also contains all the lines in
# FILE_C in the order of that file. @b_array is a bit different, it
# also contains all of the lines in FILE_B **except for those lines
# whose first column were already in FILE_A.
# 
# You don't specify exactly what you want done at this point. Do
# you want to combine @a_array with @b_array? Here's how we can do
# that:

my @combined_array = sort (@a_array, @b_array);
```

Now, you have three arrays that represented your three file, and the order of these three arrays are the same as your files.

`@a_array` and `@c_array` contain all of the lines that were in `a.txt` and `c.txt` respectively. `@b_array` contains all the lines that were in `b.txt`, but not in `a.txt`.

Now, you can take these three arrays and merge them the way you want to merge them.

Comment: Thanks a lot David. Much appreciated for your quick and clear help.

Your question:
And, what do you mean by matching line? Do you mean the full line matches, or only up to the first semicolon matches?
My Clarification:
1. c.txt is the output file, which contains the lines from a.txt and b.txt.
2. I need all the lines from a.txt to c.txt.
3. But I only need the lines from b.txt to c.txt, where first column
of b.txt is not present in a.txt. So, its not entire line matching, its first field comparision [x001, x002 etc, but it not always starts with x charecter].

Can you help?

Comment: @user2789629 In this case, you want to build your index not based upon the entire line, but upon the part of the line from the beginning of the line to the semicolon. You can use a [regular expression](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut) for that. In the above, I do a _match_ on the line using `$line =~ /^(.+?);/;` This will match the part of the line up to the semicolon and save it in `$1`. I then use that as my indexing key.

Comment: thanks for your reply again. But as mentioned I'm not that brilliant in perl programming. Hence, finding it difficult to understand your answer. If you don't mind could you edit your program, so that I can understand from that? 

Regards, Kirti.

Comment: @user2789629 I've added comments explaining each part. If you need to understand a particular command and what it's doing, see http://perldoc.perl.org. It's the complete Perl documentation.

Comment: David, love the way you teached and helped. You're a great human being.

Couple of clarifactions to your question:

we no need of populating c.txt into another array, this c.txt should contain merged output for a.txt and b.txt as I've showned in my example. Hence, I've slightly modified the program to populate c.txt from a.txt and b.txt. But getting below error:

Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at ./test.pl line 34, <$b_fh> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $1 in exists at ./test.pl line 35, <$b_fh> line 1.

Please please help me, last time :)

Regards / Kirti.

Comment: Love you David, your solution worked.. you're inspiring me to learn PERL and build my career ;) love again with many kisses.

Comment: You have `$line = /^(.+?);/;` in your answer where you meant `$line =~ /^(.+?);/;`.

Comment: $line = /^(.+?);/; was throughing an uninitialized value error. Hence I've slightly modified that line to $line =~ /^(.+?);/; . That worked. Please correct me,if something is wrong.

Comment: @BradGilbert Thx. Been fixed.